# Microsoft SQL Server calculate total time between successive events

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, date-arithmetic

First post here, but can anyone  guide or help me understand the following problem.For the following table "Patient_Table", how can i find out the total number of days patient_id 22 was sick.

```
ID    Patient_ID     Listing_Number     Date              Status 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1     22              1                  01/01/2016        Healthy
2     22              2                  01/11/2016        Sick
3     34              1                  01/13/2016        Healthy
4     22              3                  01/20/2016        Healthy
5     22              4                  01/22/2016        Sick
6     22              5                  01/23/2016        Healthy
```

below is my logic so far, but i'm not sure of the proper syntax.

```
declare 
@count      int = 1, 
@Days_sicks int = 0 

while   @count <= (select max (Listing_number) from Patient_Table where Patient_id = '22')

begin 
    case
    when (select status from Patient_Table where Patient_id = '22' and Listing_number = @count) = 'Sick'
    then @Days_sicks = @Days_sicks + datediff('dd',  (select min date from Patient_Table where patient_id = 22 and listing_number >  @count and status != 'Sick'), (select date from patient_table where patient_id = 22 and listing_number = @count)
    else   @Days_sicks 
    end as Days_sicks

set @Count = @Count + 1 
END;
```

---

I've also tried this one but it's not working very well and i'm having issue with the group by clause

```
SELECT t1.patient_id, 
    DATEDIFF(dd,
        t1.date,
        (SELECT MIN(t3.date)
        FROM Patient_Table t3
        WHERE t3.patient_id = t1.patient_id
        AND t3.date> t1.date) as Days_sicks
    )
FROM Patient_Table t1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NEXT'
    FROM Patient_Table t2
   WHERE t2.patient_id = t1.patient_id
   AND t2.date> t1.date
   AND t2.status != 'sick')
   and t1.patient_id = '22'
```

Desired Result

```
Patient id    Days_sicks
22            10
```

Comment: What's the logic of the quesiton, min(date) till max(date) where status = 'Sick'?

Comment: could you please specify sql-server version

Comment: @why 10? should it not be 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lead()` function and then aggregation:

```
select patient_id,
       sum(datediff(day, date, coalesce(next_date, getdate())))
from (select pt.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by patient_id order by date) as next_date
      from patient_table pt
     ) pt
where status = 'Sick'
group by patient_id;
```

Note:  If someone is currently sick, then this uses the current date for the end of the "sick" state.

Also, this will work if the patient is sick on multiple visits.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select s.Patient_ID, 
   sum(datediff(day, s.Date, coalesce(h.date, getdate()) totalDaysSick 
From table s left join table h 
   on h.Patient_ID = s.Patient_ID 
     and h.Status = 'Healthy'
     and s.Status ='Sick'  
     and h.Date = (Select Min(date) from table 
                   where Patient_ID = s.Patient_ID
                     and Date > s.Date)
Group By Patient_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lag` windowing function and order by date, then do a datediff to find the number of days between current and previous date. Then do a sum on the number of days:

```
select
    sickdays.Patient_ID
    ,Sum(sickdays.DayNums) as SickDays
from
    (select
            Patient_ID
            ,Datediff(day, Lag([Date], 1, null) over (order by [Date]), [Date]) as DayNums

        from Patient
        where Patient_ID = 22
        and Status = 'Sick'
        group by    Patient_ID
                    ,Date) as sickdays
where
    sickdays.DayNums is not null
group by sickdays.Patient_ID
```